# Find a Regex Pattern in a String

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to print out a pattern from a string.

```
String stringToProcess = "Test Test Hello World Test Test";
String pattern = "Hello\\sWorld";
System.out.println(stringToProcess.substring(stringToProcess.indexOf(pattern), stringToProcess.lastIndexOf(pattern)));
```

When I run this code it seems to give lots of errors depending on how I try to change it and repair it. As it is above, it gives the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`

**Please note:** I already am aware of the `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern);` way of doing this. I would like to do it in a different way.

Comment: `indexOf()` doesn't work with regex, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: The only other way I am aware of is to use `Matcher.start()` .... but that involves `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern)` which you already know.

Comment: use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` and use `start()` and `end()` (also your `\s` should be `\\s`.

Comment: Could you possibly post an example in an answer?

Comment: Why don't you just use `String pattern = "Hello World";`? I.e. you don't need a regex to define a a space symbol.

Comment: I want to use regex though... So I know how to do it

Comment: if you intend to extract substrings based on matched patterns, you have to use `Pattern` way of java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your requested example:

```
    String stringToProcess = "Test Test Hello World Test Test";
    String patternString = "Hello\\sWorld";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToProcess);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int start = matcher.start();
        int end = matcher.end();
        System.out.println(stringToProcess.substring(start, end));
    }
```

Beacause you really wanted to use `\\s` instead of a blank, it will also match `Hello\tWorld`,  `Hello\nWorld` and all other possible single whitespace character between Hello and World.

The way I have it written it will only print the first found match (if there is one), if you want of print all matches to your pattern replace `if` with `while`.

But I wouldn't use `start()`, `end()` and `substring()` if I didn't have to, you can just print `matcher.group()` if you want to print your match.

Answer (score 0):

This is function that return the start location of the sentence :

```
public  static int decodeString(String msg,String sentence) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)"+sentence+"(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);
        if (m.matches()) {
           return  m.end(1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Note that this give the last matching. If we have some matches we need to work with loop